# How to create pcolormesh with the mean of a set of data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I use this set of data and plot it using pcolormesh? the data is as follows:

```
array([[    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
        0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
   [   34.19227552,    34.19246389,    34.19265956, ...,
       34.19284295,    34.19253446,    34.1923012 ],
   [   68.46819899,    68.46861825,    68.46892983, ...,
       68.46895204,    68.46856004,    68.46812476],
   ..., 
   [ 3937.42832088,  3937.42522049,  3937.43673897, ...,
     3937.43603929,  3937.44434961,  3937.43535423],
   [ 3987.08591207,  3987.082997  ,  3987.09487184, ...,
     3987.09300137,  3987.10157045,  3987.09271431],
   [ 4037.00035477,  4036.9977684 ,  4037.01006508, ...,
     4037.00674248,  4037.01561165,  4037.00689316]])
```

I need to plot this data into a 3D pcolormesh matplotlib. How do I do this? If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it, as I really need help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can follow this turorials:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html

or

http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.3/tutorial.html

Load the modules:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import mlpy
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # required for plotting
```

Load the Iris dataset:

```
>>> iris = np.loadtxt('iris.csv', delimiter=',')
>>> x, y = iris[:, :4], iris[:, 4].astype(np.int) # x: (observations x attributes) matrix, y: classes (1: setosa, 2: versicolor, 3: virginica)
>>> x.shape
(150, 4)
>>> y.shape
(150, )
```

Comment: I tried that already but I keep getting errors saying that the data is too big. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Now it's telling me that there's no module named mlpy! Is it a module that I have to download through command prompt?

Comment: Yes, you have to install it.Follow this:http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.5/install.html

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but it's telling me that I need python 2.6 for it to work, but I have to use python 3.5 for work. How can I fix this? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No definitly not: documentation says: Python >= 2.6 or 3.X. It should say 2.6 or higher, show me the message. Also what OS?

Comment: Windows 10 OS i'm using

Comment: The message just says I need python 2.6 for this module that's it

Comment: Ok now I know: for windows it says: Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2 Windows installer (x86). So you are on 3.5 so you cannot use installer. Python 3.2 is the latest that could work with installer

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/MLPY/html/install.html with: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mlpy/files/mlpy%203.5.0/mlpy-3.5.0.tar.gz/download